# What is the spawn rate of Creepers in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in my Minecraft world and saw a ton of monsters in a dark room, I saw creepers there mixed in with he crowd. Since all these were randomly spawned by the game I wondered what their spawn rate was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing about spawn rate. They are all the same. But what you might have seen was a pack. (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Pack_spawning)

Comment: Thank you. That's useful. But aren't mobs like Endermen less common than Creepers?

Comment: @RobertLane Excuse me for the INCREDIBLY late response. But, Enderman has a lot more spawning conditions

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, the game would spawn a pack instead of a single entity where the game would select a random location on a chunk to be the center of the pack

Answer (score 1):

Zombies, spiders, and skeletons are most common, then endermen and creepers, then blazes and the rest of the harmful mobs are very rare.